# Configure docker not to start any containers when it restarts

Tags: docker

Sometimes my computer crashes and I have to restart it. When it restarts, it starts docker up again. When docker starts up, it starts up my previous containers. This can cause complications, such as not have a reliable internet connection in chrome, which took me about an hour of hair-pulling to resolve.

My solution to this, to save my computer some startup load, and avoid some hair-pulling, is to avoid starting up the containers at all, and start them manually instead. My reasons for this are:

- I don't always need to start docker
- I can work out that docker isn't running in a fraction of a second due to habit and repetition.

Unfortunately my understanding of docker is limited. I know that I could change all my docker-compose configurations to never restart, but according to my understanding (which I am prepared to believe is flawed) that would also mean the containers won't automatically restart when I'm attempting to run them manually.

Ideally I'd have them not start up when docker starts up, but restart whenever I'm starting them through docker-compose.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why start Docker at all at system start then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `restart-policy` for a container or a service to `no`. This will prevent docker containers from restarting themselves automatically. In case you do not use docker frequently, I'd suggest you go with daniu's advice in the comment and remove docker daemon from starting at reboot.

[Restart-Policy at Docker's official website](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically)